# Отрисовка нестандартных фигур canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Нужна какая-то библиотека или фреймворк для работы с canvas чтобы отрисовывать фигуры по набору координат, которые будут идти упорядоченно(то есть их нужно просто последовательно соединять). Пытался что-то нагуглить но без особого успеха, везде просто говорят про набор нестандартных фигур и все. Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: Встроенные beginPath, moveTo, lineTo не подходят?

Comment: Подходят в принципе, я с ними пока и сделал, но хотелось бы нечто более удобное, если есть такая возможность, просто хотелось бы поверх этого добавить возможность зумить изображение туда сюда и строить изображение в абстрактной системе координат. То есть я даю массив координат, строится изображение в канвасе которое можно приближать и отдалять, что будет слишком трудоемкой для меня задачей, так как пока я только по пикселям могу это делать.